# how can I use sql transactions?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have a Mysql server with ndbcluster engine which supports transactions.

I want to use transactions with my Java application under tomcat 6 with Spring JDBC framework 3.0.6.

I have a DataSource bean called idDataSource configured in my web.xml.

i added the following:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="idDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

to create the txManager bean.

I read the docs at the following url: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

unfortunately I'm really really lost. I understood that I may need to implement some kind of transaction interface but I have no idea which. any information would be greatly appreciated!!!

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the framework that you want to create a transaction 'around' your method(s). Personally, I've always gone the way of using annotations ([@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html), `<tx:annotation-driven/>`). There are lots of tutorials and examples floating around the 'net, for example: http://blog.m1key.me/2010/06/spring-3-transaction-management.html

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides you with two options:

1. Declarative Transaction
2. Programmatic Transaction support

Depending on which one you want to use your remaining code depends, easiest is Declarative Transaction,

Add @Transactional to your DAO class and you are done.

Following Links should provide you with some examples:

1. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Spring/SetupDataSourceforMySQL.htm
2. http://www.devdaily.com/java/spring-mysql-java-basicdatasource-connection-example